# proguard.ParseException: Unknown option '-encryptstrings' in proguard.cfg

Tags: android-proguard, dexguard

When I run mvn install goal with progurad option then am getting the following error. Previously, I don't have this error. I could not find what has made the difference in getting the following error:

```
 proguard.ParseException: Unknown option '-encryptstrings' in line .. of file 'proguard.cfg'
```

**I am using dexguard for my project. is this error because of the maven could not identify the dexguard folder location?**

proguard.cfg content:

```
-dalvik  -- unknown option
-android -- unknown option
# Encrypt all strings  -- parse exception
-encryptstrings '???*'
```

The following works with out issues:

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-optimizationpasses 30
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify
-dontoptimize
-ignorewarnings
-renamesourcefileattribute Maviance
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*
-keep,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class android.support.**Compat* { *; }
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I use dexguard and gradle seems to use proguard instead

Answer (score 1):

The option `-encryptstrings '???*'` is only supported by DexGuard. So when you use ProGuard to build your application, you will receive such an error.

Thus it is advised to separate the dexguard related configuration into a separate config file `dexguard-project.txt` that is only included when using DexGuard.

Comment: Thank you. I have moved to dexguard-project.txt file. How does I let maven consider this file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using dexguard. The problem was that I was missing this line

```
            proguardFiles getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
```

So gradle took Proguard instead of Dexguard, which obviously doesn´t have the encryptstrings feature. So the working release configuration is this:

```
  release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
```